# Is it possible to have a cell in table1 "point to" a cell in table2?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a hierarchical structure in a database driven software application.

Each row in parentTable 'owns' a number of rows in childTable.

If the childTable does not have a value set in columnA then it should return the value specified in the appropriate row of parentTable columnB.

Is it possible to implement a pointer or cell reference somehow so that I do not have to copy values from parent to child.

(A change in parent could result in a large number of changes in child).

If this is not possible, could anyone suggest a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW after one year, a normal `JOIN` between parent and child and using the `ISNULL` function would suffice. There is no need to start duplicating data.

```
SELECT ISNULL(c.columnA, p.columnB)
FROM   childTable c
       INNER JOIN parentTable t ON t.ID = c.ParentID
```

Comment: A delayed answer and a slightly delayed acceptance.
This doesn't do exactly what I had in mind when I wrote the question, but provides a very nice alternative solution that would allow me to achieve the same result.
For some reason the idea of using ISNULL with an alternate column instead of just a default value never crossed my mind!
Thanks for taking the time to respond :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your data structure is wrong if you have copied data in the child table. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

If you are denormalising for speed then the number of copies shouldn't be a problem as it would be less copies than calculation on the fly.

Comment: I have a scenario where there will be a Parent default value, but this is overridden by the child value if one is specified. I could leave the child data as null unless one is specified, but rather than checking for null, then querying the parent table afterwards I had hoped I could keep the child value valid so only ever have to read from there.

Comment: surely you would just get both in 1 query and then decide which to use in your program?